# How to Fetch the Values by text name using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am reading the following URL

I want to fetch the following values by text name

**Last Price** value (which is 7976.75)

and

**Change Value** (which is 14.1)

I was trying it this way

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException,ParseException {


    try
    {
        Document doc1 = null;
        doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://test/1").timeout(10 * 1000).get();
        String body = doc1.body().toString();
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(body);

         String  current_val = doc.select("div:contains(Last Price)").first().toString();
            System.out.println("THE INDEX VALUE IS" +current_val);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Could you please let me know how to retrive Last Price and Change Value Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


            try
            {
                Document doc1 = null;
                doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.test/1").timeout(10 * 1000).get();
                String body = doc1.body().toString();
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(body);

                String current_val = doc.select("ul:contains(Last Price)").select("li").last().text();

                System.out.println("THE INDEX VALUE IS" +current_val);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , the Index value is fetched correctly , similarly i tried to fetch the change value also this way     String change_val = doc.select("ul:contains(Change)").select("li").last().text();

                System.out.println("THE change_val VALUE IS" +change_val); , but its returning empty , could you please tell me how to retrieve the change value also

Comment: i can see more change li which one you want?

Comment: Thanks for responding  , i want it the one with the value 17.25

Comment: Try this working for me`String current_val = doc.select("ul:contains(Change)").select("li").get(1).text();`